# How do I login pre-authenticated users?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How do I login users using pre-authenticated authentication request?

Authentication is handled by https://www.netiq.com/ and requests are passed to Meteor with http headers that contain username, roles etc. How can I populate user objects in Meteor and do authorization?

Coming from Java and Spring Security, I used https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java

Comment: Can you provide more information on the architecture involved? Specifically, what authentication/credential information is passed from where to where, when, and how? For example, does netiq server pass information to the Meteor server, or does it only communicate with the browser?

Comment: Authentication information is added as http request headers coming into the meteor server. So the user is already authenticated.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html

Comment: Simple example. Meteor is running on localhost:3000, netiq on http://myservice:80. I go to http://myservice:80, login, and requests with added http request headers with my username etc is sent to localhost:3000.  http://myservice:80 is like a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, register a login handler using something like this (untested):

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler("netiqPreauth", function(options) {
  var self = this;
  if (! options || ! options.netiqPreauth || 
      ! self.connection || ! self.connection.httpHeaders) {
    return undefined;
  }

  // parseHeaders() parses the headers into a userDetails object.
  var userDetails = parseHeaders(self.connection.httpHeaders);

  // Code below assumes userDetails.username is unique
  var existingUser = Meteor.user.findOne({ "services.netiq.username": userDetails.username });
  if (existingUser) {
    if (EJSON.stringify(existingUser.services.netiq) !== EJSON.stringify(userDetails)) {
      Meteor.users.update(existingUser._id, { 
        $set: { "services.netiq": userDetails }, // Update details
        $unset: { "services.resume.loginTokens": "" } // Force logout
      });
    }
    return { userId: existingUser._id };
  }  
  var newUserId = Accounts.insertUserDoc(options, {
    profile: { /* whatever */ }, // Optional
    services: {
      netiq: userDetails
    }  
  });
  return {
    userId: newUserId
  };
});
```

That will only update the details associated with a user when the user logs in. If you have some way to notify the server when a user's details change, you can have the server update the details and delete the existing tokens associated with the user (like in the code above). Deleting the tokens will logout the user anywhere they might be logged in. Deleting a user will also log the user out.

If you don't have a way to be notified about changes to a user's details, you could also call `Accounts.config({ loginExpirationInDays: some_suitably_short_time_period } )` (on the client and server) to log out users frequently.

To log a user *in*, you need to call `Accounts.callLoginMethod()` on the client. If you want to automatically log the user back in when he is logged out, you could do something like this (untested):

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
      if (! Meteor.userId()) {
        Accounts.callLoginMethod({
          methodArguments: [{
            netiqPreauth: true
          }],
          userCallback: function (error) {
            if (error) {
              // handle error
            } else {
              // handle success
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed. I haven't tested it, but it all seems to make sense. I'm a bit surprised though that this is not documented or asked for here before. It is quite a common thing in enterprises.